# New ckeditor's plugin is not showing

Tags: python, django, text, ckeditor

I am trying to add a `Plugin in django-ckeditor` in my BlogApp.

**How i am trying to do :-**

I have downloaded a plugin from `ckeditor site` named [hkemoji](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/hkemoji) and I have pasted it in the main plugins file of ckeditor but when i try to check in browser then it is not showing in Browser.

I have seen many tutorial but nothing worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install CKEditor properly and then it will work in Django.

First Install pip install django-ckeditor plugin and then go to Settings.py and edit the installed app's part

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'admissions',
    'ckeditor',
]

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {'default': { 'toolbar_Full': [['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],['TextColor', 'BGColor'],['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'],['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],['NumberedList','BulletedList'],['Indent','Outdent'],['Maximize'],],'extraPlugins': 'justify,liststyle,indent',},}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly in django. **The Problem is** that it is not showing my new custom plugin.

Comment: Do you have any idea of `How can i add a new custom plugin in django-ckeditor` ?